# Google Cloud Spanner: Aborted due to transient fault

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I have Table in Google Cloud Spanner that is multiple TB in size.

I'm trying to execute a larger DELETE statement on this table:

```
gcloud spanner databases execute-sql production --instance=keys --enable-partitioned-dml --sql="DELETE FROM keys WHERE datetime >= '2018-01-01T00:00:00Z' AND datetime <= '2018-12-31T23:59:59Z'" --timeout=100000000
```

Unfortunately this won't execute, instead I'm getting:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.spanner.databases.execute-sql) ABORTED: Aborted due to transient fault
```

Essentially I can't DELETE any rows from my Spanner Table, even when selecting a smaller set (e.g. deleting just a day instead of the whole year).
What could be the issue here?

**EDIT:
The Schema of the table is as follows:**

```
CREATE TABLE keys (
  key STRING(MAX),
  data STRING(MAX),
  datetime TIMESTAMP,
) PRIMARY KEY (key)
```

Comment: Hello @user9114945, It's not clear for me why you are receiving this error. As Cloud Spanner is a special poduct, I suggest that you [open a support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/procedures#create_a_support_case) on GCP (If you have support package). You will receive more help and get detailed explanation on your issue there.

Comment: Can you please share your schema? Perhaps try filtering on a prefix of the primary key to reduce the number of scanned rows.

Comment: Hey Rose, I have updated the post with Schema. Thank you for your input with prefix filtering, I will try that in combination with my other delete conditions

Comment: I reproduced your scenario and is working fine for me. 
So, can you please confirm the structure I have understood so far for the names:
Spanner instance: keys
Database on the instance: production
Table on the database: keys 
Am I right?

Comment: Thank you TasosV, I think the problem is that my table is multiple TB in size. I found a semi-solution using Rose proposal. This way at the moment I manage to delete around 300k rows every 5 minutes. Which is nothing, but still something.

Comment: I think you should take a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/quotas#limits_for_creating_reading_updating_and_deleting_data)

Answer (score 0):

Filtering on a prefix of the primary key will reduce the number of scanned rows and avoid the error.